# Spark Java API to create schema from config file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for an approach to read table schema from a config file, to avoid hardcoding it in Spark (Java). For example, to read two .csv files I create schemas as below:

#1

```
    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
            DataTypes.createStructField("emp_dept",StringType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("empid",IntegerType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("empdesignation",StringType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("emp_salary",IntegerType, true) 
    });
    Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read().format("csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .schema(schema)
            .csv(path);
```

#2

```
    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
            DataTypes.createStructField("emp_details",StringType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("empid",IntegerType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("empfistname",StringType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("emplastname,IntegerType, true) 
    });
    Dataset<Row> df2  = spark.read().format("csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .schema(schema)
            .csv(path);
```

Instead of creating multiple schemas like this, I'd like to create it a from config file.

Comment: is iti okay if the schema is comming from case class ?

Comment: Thank You For Replying @AbdennacerLachiheb  is it Scala case class?

Comment: Yes, I think it will be easier to do it from a scala case class, rather than parsing a config file , but it dependents from your need

Comment: I want  Schema in java spark 
any  best approach in java spark is fine for me